# Coverting json array using retrofit?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

this is my Json

```
[  
{  
  "nata_center":{  
     "id":67,
     "nata_center_name":"Primo Institute of Design"
  }
 },
{  
  "nata_center":{  
     "id":68,
     "nata_center_name":"Sai Ganesh Institute"
  }
 }
]
```

Pojo classes

```
public class Explorer {
    NataCenter nataCenter;

    public NataCenter getNataCenter() {
        return nataCenter;
    }

    public void setNataCenter(NataCenter nataCenter) {
        this.nataCenter = nataCenter;
    }
}
```

2)

```
public class NataCenter {
    public String id;
    public String nata_center_name;

     public NataCenter(String id,String nata_center_name)
     {
      this.id=id;
     this.nata_center_name=nata_center_name;
     }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getNata_center_name() {
        return nata_center_name;
    }

    public void setNata_center_name(String nata_center_name) {
        this.nata_center_name = nata_center_name;
    }
}
```

GetMethhodinRetrofit

```
void getCenter(@Query("id") int id,Callback<List<Explorer>> callback);
```

MainActvitiy.java

```
       service.getCenter(i,new Callback<List<Explorer>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(List<Explorer> o, Response response) {
                            Log.d(TAG,"Success" + "Response"+o.toString());

                        @Override
                        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                            Log.d(TAG,"Failed"+error.toString());

                        }
                    });
```

This is the error message

```
 Failedretrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Comment: Can you change something in json?

Comment: ya sure is there any problem with json?

Comment: For me no :) but if you add one more tag will be easer

Comment: So can I modify json or do you want to have json which look like your?

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak ya sure .but if i add it will work?

Comment: I give you solution :)  No I am trying to create solution for you json. If it will not work I will tell you what you have to do. Give me a few min :)

Comment: I did - it works for you json - Please check and inform me that it works for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically the problem is that you have array as root in json. You have to create object which will be used as container for this list and deserializator for this object. I used Explorer as container, it looks like below:

```
public class Explorer {

    List<NataCenter> nataCenter;


    public List<NataCenter> getNataCenter() {
        return nataCenter;
    }

    public void add(NataCenter nataCenterItem){
        if(nataCenter == null){
            nataCenter = new LinkedList<>();
        }
        nataCenter.add(nataCenterItem);
    }
}
```

My solution is just explanation. You can improve your `Explorer` class. Setter for list is not the best idea.

The NataCenter class looks like previous,

The one of important think is `ExplorerDeserializerJson` class. It is used to deserialize json and it looks like below:

```
public class ExplorerDeserializerJson implements JsonDeserializer<Explorer> {

    @Override
    public Explorer deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc)
            throws JsonParseException {
        Explorer explorer = new Explorer();
        JsonArray jsonArray = je.getAsJsonArray();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        for(JsonElement element : jsonArray){
            JsonObject jsonObject = element.getAsJsonObject();
            NataCenter nataCenter = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.get("nata_center"), NataCenter.class);
            explorer.add(nataCenter);
        }
        return explorer;

    }
}
```

Additionally I change your client. Now `Explorer` is a response.

```
void getCenter(@Query("id") int id,Callback<Explorer> callback);
```

As the last you have to register new deserializer in the place where you create RestAdapter as is shown below:

```
 RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                   .setEndpoint(BuildConfig.IP)
                    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(new GsonBuilder()
                            .registerTypeAdapter(Explorer.class, new ExplorerDeserializerJson())
                            .create()))
                    .build();
            restAdapter.create(CenterClient.class).getCenter(1);
```

Comment: i willl check and let u know

Comment: @when i tried Log.d(TAG,o.getNataCenter().get(0).getNata_center_name()); something like this.

Comment: What is `o` ? Which class instance is it?

Comment: o is Explorer variable

Comment: @Thanks a lot.i will check

Comment: I am sorry the problem was in Deserializer I fixed it. Please use new ExplorerDeserializer