# How to use retrofit as a singleton while using gson convertor?

Tags: java, android, rest, gson, retrofit

> From the @jake Wharton answer    you should only ever call restAdapter.create once and re-use the same instance of MyTaskService every time you need to interact with.
>   I cannot stress this enough.
>   You can use the regular singleton pattern in order to ensure that there only is ever a single instance of these objects that you use everywhere. A dependency injection framework would also be something that could be used to manage these instances but would be a bit overkill if you are not already utilizing it.

this is my code

```
public class MusicApi {
private static final String API_URL = "https://itunes.apple.com";
private static MusicApiInterface sMusicApiInterface;

public static MusicApiInterface getApi() {
    if (sMusicApiInterface == null) {
        sMusicApiInterface = null;
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(API_URL)
                .build();

        sMusicApiInterface = restAdapter.create(MusicApiInterface.class);
    }
    return sMusicApiInterface;
}

public interface MusicApiInterface {
    @GET("/search?entity=musicVideo")
    NetworkResponse getMusic(@Query("term") String term);

    @GET("/search?entity=musicVideo")
    void getMusic(@Query("term") String term, Callback<NetworkResponse> networkResponseCallback);

    @GET("/search?entity=musicVideo")
    Observable<NetworkResponse> getMusicObservable(@Query("term") String term);
}
```

}

Everything works fine. I am using type adapter, For each request I need to create different type of gson parse and setting into adapter.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(DiscussionViewMoreContainer.class, new ExplorerDeserializerJson())
            .create();
```

it makes me that i have to create a new restadapter every time. In my app some requests are running parallely.is this correct way?

Comment: *it makes me that i have to create a new restadapter everytime.* why ?

Comment: @Blackbelt after making rest adapter as singleton.how you will set  the gson convertor into restadpater.will you create a new rest builder and set it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you don't have to create it every time, but just once, when you create your RestAdapter:

```
public static MusicApiInterface getApi() {
    if (sMusicApiInterface == null) {
       Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
           .registerTypeAdapter(DiscussionViewMoreContainer.class, new ExplorerDeserializerJson())
           .create();
       RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(API_URL)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .build();
       sMusicApiInterface = restAdapter.create(MusicApiInterface.class);
     }
     return sMusicApiInterface;
}
```

if you need to register more than one `Deserializer`, just call .`registerTypeAdapter` multiple times with the pair `Class/TypeToken` and instance of the custom `Deserializer`. Gson will call correct one depending on the return type of the retrofit's method you are calling. E.g

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
           .registerTypeAdapter(DiscussionViewMoreContainer.class, new ExplorerDeserializerJson())
           .registerTypeAdapter(OtherModelClass.class, new OtherModelClassDeserializerJson())
           .registerTypeAdapter(OtherModelClass3.class, new OtherModelClass3DeserializerJson())
```

Comment: i have different class for register typer adapter .Example

Comment: i have different set of type adapter ,Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(GalleryContainer.class, new ExplorerDeserializerJson())
            .create();...How you wil register next time?

Comment: you can call `registerTypeAdapter` multiple times.

Comment: @when i make as singleton it will be created once..right?how u will change ?unless u create new builder and refer to existing  object, when my requests are running parallel ,if i change, everything will work?

Comment: if you need to change it, you don't need a singleton. I still don't get if the issue is with the singleton pattern or with Gson

Comment: there is no method called restadapter.setadapter();

Comment: without recreating the whole thing no. Could you just tell me what you need, maybe there is another way ?

Comment: i have two set of nested class which is executing in parellell.each nested class has list of arrays.i am explicitly using json deserilaizer . in some pages i am calling 5 request.every time i am creating new retrofit object and service..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94155/discussion-between-asthme-and-blackbelt).

Comment: *For each request i need to create different type of gson parse and setting into adapter.* why you need that ?

Comment: because each request contains different and various type of nested class.so i have to create different  type of deserializer

Comment: you really don't. Deserializer are you usually to handle particular cases. Most of the time you don't need them. Could you post an example of response ?

Comment: in my case all request has deserilaizer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29169640/coverting-json-array-using-retrofit see this

Comment: I see.. Assuming that you need all those custom deserializer, you have to call registerTypeAdapter multiple times, providing the different pair class/deserializer's object. Gson will call the correct one

Comment: yup.is there a way to do?

Comment: you just have to call registerAdapter multiple times. See my edit. Then accordingly to what you declare in MusicApiInterface the correct Deserializer will be called

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete code for Singletone RestAdapter & ApiInterface class. We can use RxJava2CallAdapterFactory also if we use RxAndroid.

```
import com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.RxJava2CallAdapterFactory;
import kaj.service.customer.utility.ApplicationData;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

/**
 * Created by @ShihabMama 20/12/18 5.02 AM :)
 */

public class RestAdapter {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    private static ApiInterface apiInterface;

    public static ApiInterface getRxClient() {
        if (apiInterface == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(ApplicationData.FINAL_URL)
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
        }
        return apiInterface;
    }

    public static ApiInterface getApiClient() {
        if (apiInterface == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(ApplicationData.FINAL_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
        }
        return apiInterface;
    }

}
```

ApiInterface class

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

/**
 * Created by @Shihab_Mama on 11/25/2016.
 */
public interface ApiInterface {

    // TODO: 12/20/2018 sample below
    @GET("orderapi/getOrders?")
    Call<OrderListModel> getOrders(
            @Query("accessToken") String accessToken,
            @Query("companyId") String companyId,
            @Query("customerId") int customerId);

    @POST("orderapi/placeOrder")
    Call<PlaceOrderResponseModel> placeOrder(
            @Query("accessToken") String accessToken,
            @Query("companyId") String companyId,
            @Query("branchId") int branchId,
            @Query("customerId") int customerId,
            @Query("orderNo") String orderNo,
            @Query("orderItemList") String orderItemList,
            @Query("discountedTotalBill") String discountedTotalBill,
            @Query("discountedTotalVat") String discountedTotalVat);

}
```